# How do I obtain and set-up a "messaging provider" for a JAXM client to call an asynchronous SOAP API?

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

I am trying to use JAXM to create a client that would call a third-party asynchronous SOAP API.  According to the JAXM documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5452/wsgjaxm.html#wp41528), a "messaging provider" is required for asynchronous calls.

I see that I would need to use the ProviderConnectionFactory for asynchronous calls (http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS03/19560-P/Docs/JWSDP/tutorial/doc/JAXM4.html), but I don't know how to obtain (and set-up) a "messaging provider".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact your service provider.

There are several asynchronous queuing systems available and you will need to use the same one as your service provider.

Having installed the appropriate software you will also need to configure the a connection to the service.

Comment: Based on the documentation I've already read, this makes sense.  Thanks for the direction.